# HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'

Tags: token, csrf, status

I am getting the error 
HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'
when I click on the login button.
The HTML file is as follows. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Login page</title>
<style>
.error {
    color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login page</h1>

<p>
<c:if test="${error == true}">
    <b class="error">Invalid login or password.</b>
</c:if>
</p>

<form method="post" action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check'/>" >
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Login:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username"size="30" maxlength="40"  /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password" size="30" maxlength="32" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form> 

<p>
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.html">Home page</a><br/>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using spring security and posting a form of username and password but have forgotten to include `_csrf` token when posting the form. 
For spring security documentation:

> 13.4.3 Include the CSRF Token
>
> Form Submissions
>
> The last step is to ensure that you include the CSRF token in all
>   PATCH, POST, PUT, and DELETE methods. This can be done using the _csrf
>   request attribute to obtain the current CsrfToken. An example of doing
>   this with a JSP is shown below:

```
<c:url var="logoutUrl" value="/logout"/> 
<form action="${logoutUrl}"method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Log out" />
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"value="${_csrf.token}"/>
</form>
```

Checkout the full document [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-multipartfilter)